# Changing with header names from a merged pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, header, rename

I have a pivot table (named 'budgets') created using pandas. This looks as follows.

```
               Current Budget   
Type            C         D
Project Name        
AA            645000     90000
BB            664039     73456
CC            994654     56398
DD            3290090.46 95000
```

I merged this dataframe with another one (named 'ws_project', using

```
merged = pd.merge(budgets, ws_project, on=['Project Name'],how='inner')
```

budgets and ws_project have the same column ['Project Name'], so I merged the two using this column.

This is what the merged dataframe looks like

```
    Project Name    ('Current Budget', 'C') ('Current Budget', 'D') Project Status
0   AA  645000  90000   Active
1   BB  664039  73456   Active
2   CC  994654  56398   Active
3   DD  3290090.46  95000   Active
```

As you can see, the column names now are ('Current Budget', 'C') and ('Current Budget', 'D'). For some reasons, I cannot use the keys. It brings a Key Error. Thus, I have tried to replace the column name thru

```
merged.columns = merged.columns.str.replace("('Current Budget', 'D')", "")
```

But this command delete the header names for BOTH ('Current Budget', 'D') and ('Current Budget', 'C') even if I tried to replace only one. I don't understand why both are deleted.

I think I can solve my issue if one of the following two questions is answered.

1. How would I delete the 'Current Budget' header in 'budgets'??

budget.iloc[0] indicates the row of (AA            645000     90000), not 'Current Budget'.

2. How can I change the column names in the merged dataframe?

merged["Design_Budget"] = merged["('Current Budget', 'D')"] brings KeyError: 'Current Budget'

merged.columns = merged.columns.str.replace() does not work. It just deletes the column names for both.

merged = merged.rename(columns={"('Current Budget', 'D')": "D", "('Current Budget', 'C')": "C"}) does not change any.

Comment: What columns do you want to be left with? i.e ["Project Name","D","C"]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you should steer clear of giving column names with any "special characters" i.e characters that have meaning other than strings in the language.

The easiest way to rename the columns is to use the following

```
 merged.columns =  ["Project Name","D","C"]
```

The first dataFrame has a hierarchical index which you could also remove like so

```
budgets.columns = budgets.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

But the former is shorter I think.

Comment: Thanks! For the first solution, can I just name one of the columns, like merge.columns[2] = ['C']? I see an error and wonder if there is anyway to do something similar to this. The second solution perfectly worked!!

Comment: Could try df.columns.values[1] = "C" where values[1] denotes the position of the column in the dataFrame.